# simplest jquery to have div "position:fixed" to the bottom right corner(always.. like on scrolling down)?

Tags: jquery, css, positioning

Hello i am relatively new to jquery but i like it, was wondering if i can have a div **positioned at the bottom right corner** of the page so that it's **position remains fixed** there even when we scroll down the page.  Thereafter i need to pass a link through an image in the div to a specific anchor in the page.
It should be *short and simple*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#divid{
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: he wants bottom right, and isnt z-index needed to ensure its in front of the scrolling thing like moe noted?

Comment: left:0 will be bottom left corner ^_^

Comment: it's giving issue in ie so can i make the div float at the bottom right of the screen

Answer (score 6):

If you're okay accepting that `position:fixed` isn't supported in IE6 and IE7 has some [caveats](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html), then don't use jQuery at all:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #myFixedDiv {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        ...
    }
</style>

<div id="myFixedDiv">
    <a href="#myTargetDiv"><img src="img.gif" /></a>
</div>

<div id="myTargetDiv">
    ...
</div>
```

etc.  However, if IE6 is an issue, or if that doesn't work for whatever reason, you can just bind an event to the window `scroll` event to help out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $myFixedDiv = $('#myFixedDiv');
    var iFixedDivHeight = $myFixedDiv.outerHeight({ 'margin': true });

    $(window).bind('scroll', function(e) {
        var iWindowHeight = $(window).height();
        var iScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop(); // or document.body.scrollTop
        $myFixedDiv.css({ 'top': iWindowHeight + iScrollPosition - iFixedDivHeight });
    });
</script>
```

or something to that effect.  HTH.

Answer (score 2):

No jQuery needed

```
<div id="fixed-element" style="position:fixed; bottom:5px; right: 5px; z-index: 999">
    <a href="#myAnchor"><img src="/src/to/image.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

But if it was me, I would do this:

(Assuming the width and height of the image are 30px, using inline CSS but I'd have it in an external file)

```
<a href="#myAnchor" id="fixed-element" style="display:block; position:fixed; bottom:5px; right: 5px; z-index: 999; width: 30px; height: 30px; background:url(/src/to/image.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 transparent; text-indent: -9999">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/) out: This is how you can fix the footer which will always be visible